# How is the Lenovo U410 Ultrabook support for Ubuntu?

Tags: lenovo, ultrabook

I'm planing to buy a new laptop in some time. Especially I've been looking into **Ultrabooks**, the *Lenovo U410* looks quite good for its pricing.

How is Ubuntu supported on this ultrabook?

I will have **Ubuntu only** probably so the problem about dual OS on this laptop should be solved.

Do the sound, battery life, wireless, quick booting + other stuff work like they should on an **ultrabook**?

Comment: Battery might be less with Linux. With the X220, it only has Intel chips and they work great with Ubuntu.

Comment: On Windows they say that the U410 should have max around 7-9 hours of  battery power or so if I remember right. But why is it so that the battery drains faster on Linux systems? Is it explained anywhere?

Comment: The problem is that the Linux kernel cannot use all the power saving functions because they are not super stable as of now. On my X220, I only have some 5 to 5.5 hours of battery life. Accordint to Lenovo, I should be getting 9 hours. I have to try some other kernel parameters to save power, but currently, Windows uses less power.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the information about the battery support.

Comment: The power-saving issue also has to deal with the fact that the the default "ondemand" CPU governor is pretty out-dated. Something along the lines of it wakes the CPU up to see if the CPU needs to be woke up -- kind of backwards, but was never really a problem until recently.

Comment: We do not offer hardware recommedations; This should have been closed log time ago. https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8922/why-dont-we-allow-shopping-recommendations

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu isn't very compatible with lenovo u410 Here's a list of things I did for my u410.
Before install
    - Backup windows 8 for when in need

How to view partitions in Lenovo u410
    - press fn+f2 and change boot settings from raid to AHCI
    - run sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda 
 - run sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sdb

- install special files in sda and sdb then creat 2-4 gb swap or hdd (better but slower)
  (note that ssd's deteriorate as sdd is used written)
- install cryptsetup and create encrypted partition
- install grub on /dev/sda by installing boot repair
- sudo add apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot && sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot repair
- click recommended repair
- reboot
- Move Desktop files, Music, Videos, Downloads, Documents and other things (including /tmp) into HDD also known as sdb
  and create symbolic links to home
- setup trim reference Activating TRIM section
- setup normally
- First check trim by using sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep -i TRIM
- activate trim use http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/enable-trim-on-ssd-solid-state-drives.html
- add discard, noatime & nodiratime to etc/fstab to increase hard drive speeds and life
- move tmp to ram from sda
- http://apcmag.com/how-to-maximise-ssd-performance-with-linux.htm
- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic
  (read instructions for bumblebee and change launcher scripts)
- run optirun [progam] (this is to give it graphics acceleration

Comment: You should not need Boot Repair. My Lenovo worked just fine, I just had to tell the EFI which image to boot (or I may have used efibootmgr, I forget). Boot Repair does some pretty funky stuff, and I wouldn't advise using it unless you know exactly what you're doing.